# Map an object of properties where some properties do not exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently am utilising `Array.map` to create a new object containing some data:

```
const bookList = [{
   name: "Foo",
   id: "1234",
   quantity: 5,
}];

function mapBooks(bookList) {
  return {
    eventName: "ping",
    data: {
      list: {
        books:
          bookList.map(
            ({name, id, quantity }) => ({ name, id, quantity})
          )
      }
      }
    };
  }

mapBooks(bookList);

// Result:
{
  eventName: "ping",
  data: {
      list: {
          books: {
              name: "Foo",
              id: "1234",
              quantity: 5,
          }
      }
  },
}
```

This is fine in this example, but what happens when one of the items is not in the provided data?

```
const bookList = [{
   name: "Foo",
   id: "1234",
}];

mapBooks(bookList);

// Result:
{
  eventName: "ping",
  data: {
      list: {
          books: {
              name: "Foo",
              id: "1234",
              quantity: undefined,
          }
      }
  },
}
```

How can I adjust my `map` function to simply **not return** any undefined values? For example I would prefer a result like this:

```
mapBooks(bookList);

// Result:
{
  eventName: "ping",
  data: {
      list: {
          books: {
              name: "Foo",
              id: "1234",
              // quantity is simply not included
          }
      }
  },
}
```

Comment: You can't be calling `map()` if you're passing an object. But assuming you're passing an array of objects, you seem to be only using map to clone the array so you could just spread? `list: { books: [...bookList] }`

Comment: bookList.map won't work because bookList isn't an array.

Comment: Don't use destructuring, just return the object itself.

Comment: @pilchard sorry you are correct, I forgot the wrapping [] in my example. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understand the question correctly but you could something like this:

```js
const bookList = {
   name: "Foo",
   id: "1234",
   quantity: 5,
};

function mapBooks(bookList) {
  return {
    eventName: "ping",
    data: {
      list: {
        books:
          bookList.map(
            (book) => ({ ...book})
          )
      }
      }
    };
  }
```

With the power of destructuring you will only fulled the present option of the object

Comment: `bookList` isn't an array, you can't map it.

Comment: It's an array now, looks good.